# My Sub View Stop Responding after keyboard hide after appearing

Tags: ios5, ios4, iphone-5

I have few UIViewController and whose nib file size is Retina 4 Full Screen. The all Views add a subview call Bottom Menu as there child

```
 BottomMenu *bottomMenu=[[BottomMenu alloc]init ];
    [self.view addSubview:bottomMenu.view];
    [self addChildViewController:bottomMenu]; 
    [bottomMenu release];
```

Every thing work fine in IPhone 4 but in IPhone 5 if once my keyboard appears keyboardwill apear is called and when keyboard hides keyboardWillHide method is called

```
-(void)keyboardWillShow :(NSNotification*)notification {


        self.view.frame=CGRectMake(-1,-120,320,480);

}

-(void)keyboardWillHide :(NSNotification*)notification {


        self.view.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);

}
```

But after keyboard hides my BottomMenu stop responding in Iphone5 but work other views work fine and my view completely work fine in Iphone4 too. can any one tell me what is the problem

Comment: What is BottomMenu? Is it a ViewController?

Comment: Yes BottomMenu is a ViewController